# synchronized statements with "break"

Tags: java, multithreading, break, synchronized

I have used synchronized statements in my codec and there is a "break" in the block:

```
for (int j = 0; j < testPathSize; j++) {

  synchronized (lock) {
    if (kpis.get(j).getDate() > startTimeInMs) {

      if (j > 0) {
        if ((kpis.get(j).getDate() - startTimeInMs)
            > (startTimeInMs - kpis.get(j - 1).getDate())) initTestPath = j - 1;
        else initTestPath = j;
      } else initTestPath = j;

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know when break is executed, the "lock" will be released?

Thanks.

Comment: please post more code, as we cannot refer to the snippet, that you have posted, because it is too small - Eg. while/break inside synchronized block will not release the lock.

Comment: You should try to design your code so that no thread ever needs to hold a lock for any longer than it takes to update a few variables.  Google for "Optimistic Locking" to find examples of how you can achieve that even when the sequence of potentially conflicting operations is long.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever execution goes outside the scope of the `synchronized` block, the lock will be released. No matter if it is because of normal program flow, a `break`, an exception, or any other way it goes outside of the block.

The official specification of how this works can be found in paragraph [14.19 The `synchronized` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Thank you! I have understanded!

Answer (score 5):

It depends on where `break` takes your code:

- If your loop that `break` ends is contained entirely within the `synchronized` block, then `break` will not release the lock, e.g.:

  ```
  synchronized (thing) {
      for (;;) {
          break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, execution will leave `synchronized` region, releasing the lock, e.g.:

  ```
  for (;;) {
      synchronized (thing) {
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

The rule is that the lock is released when you exit `synchronized` block for any reason, or call `wait` on the lock object.

**Edit:** Your code falls under the second category, when `synchronized` block is inside the loop. Therefore, `break` will release the lock.

Comment: You're making basically the same point as me (but better). OK if I edit my code snippets in and delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The java documentations says

The synchronized statement (§14.19) computes a reference to an object; it then attempts to perform a lock action on that object's monitor and does not proceed further until the lock action has successfully completed. After the lock action has been performed, the body of the synchronized statement is executed. If execution of the body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.

A synchronized method (§8.4.3.6) automatically performs a lock action when it is invoked; its body is not executed until the lock action has successfully completed. If the method is an instance method, it locks the monitor associated with the instance for which it was invoked (that is, the object that will be known as this during execution of the body of the method). If the method is static, it locks the monitor associated with the Class object that represents the class in which the method is defined. If execution of the method's body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor.

Means is a synchronized block exits in any of java way **normally or abruptly** the lock will be relinquished. Here break; is a normal way of exit.

Please see the sample below.

```
public class LockAndBreak {
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        new Thread1("Thread : " + i, lock).start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}}

class Thread1 extends Thread {
private Object lock;

public Thread1(String name, Object lock) {
    super(name);
    this.lock = lock;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Running Thread " + this.getName());
    int i = 0;
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Printing from thread " + this.getName() + "-->" + i);
            i++;
            if (i > 9) {
                System.out.println("Existing the thread : " + this.getName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}}
```